# I want to Copy the Largest number from one file to another File?But,I get some problems while inputting the numbers

Tags: java

Whenever I try to write the Numbers like this-

```
(1
2
3
4
56)
```

It takes only the first number.What is wrong with my code.This is my code.

```
BufferedReader out = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Nos for finding highest.txt"));
PrintWriter in = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("third.txt"));
String str = " ";
str = out.readLine();
String[] numbers = str.split("\n");
int[] array = new int[numbers.length];
int count = 0;
for (String strs : numbers) {
    array[count++] = Integer.parseInt(strs);
}
int max = array[0];
for (int c : array) {
    if (c > max)
        max = c;
}

in.println(new Integer(max).toString());

in.close();

out.close();
```

If I take `while((str = out.readLine()) != null)` in the above code then it printouts all the numbers instead of printing `max(Largest Number)`.

Comment: `str.split("\n");` indicates your file has a number per line but `str = out.readLine();` reads _only one_ line (as the name says). One way to solve that would be to read the lines into the array (or better a list) in a loop and _then_ look for the max number .

Comment: Replace `str.split("\n")`; with `str.split("\w+")`.

Comment: Learn how to format your post with Markdown and properly indent your code. These skills will help you be understood on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I'll expand on my comment for formatting reasons: Assuming your file has one number per line you'll want to first read them all into a list:

```
List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
while((str = out.readLine()) != null) {
  //assuming the line is not empty and contains a valid integer
  list.add( Integer.valueOf(str) ); 
}
```

Then iterate and look for the highest number:

```
for( Integer i : list ) {
  //check for max here
}
```

Comment: It worked but output is gives 8 outputs90
90
90
90
90
90
90
90 What is happening

Comment: @VishalPanta I can't tell you since I don't know how you incorporated the suggestions and what input you were using. In fact I even don't know whether I correctly understand your first comment or not.

Comment: List<Integer> list = new LinkedList<>();
  while ((str = out.readLine()) != null) {
   // assuming the line is not empty and contains a valid integer
   list.add(Integer.valueOf(str));
   System.out.println(list);
   
   }
  Integer max = list.get(0);
  
 for (Integer i : list) {
    if( i > max){
     max = i;
     
    }
    System.out.println(max);
   in.write(max);

Comment: @VishalPanta so you get 8 numbers printed? That might be due to you putting `System.out.println(list);` etc. inside the loop. Besides that I highly suggest you use a debugger and step through your code to see where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If you input the numbers are on on the same line then split the input using space:

```
String[] numbers = str.split(" ");
```

If your numbers in the file are each in new line then use

```
String[] numbers = str.split("\n");
```

Comment: Did you try implementing this solution with the OP's code?

Comment: I tried str.split("\n") but it shows number format error.